# Compass taking too long to compile

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, susy-sass

Since updated to the latest version of Compass it now takes 4.294s to compile.

I need this version of compass due to needed `susy`

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Running "watch" task
Completed in 4.294s at Tue Sep 30 2014 23:38:01 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) - Waiting...`

// Running versions

compass -v 1.0.1
susy    -v 2.1.3
sass    -v 3.4.4
```

I compile with grunt:

```
    sass: {                              
        dist: {                          
            options: {                   
                style: 'compressed',
                require: 'susy',
                compass: true
            },
            files: {                     
                '<%= yeoman.css %>/style.css': '<%= yeoman.sass %>/style.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I speed up the compile time? Is it something wrong with my config?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a config problem, it's a [known performance regression in the latest Sass & Compass](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1019).

Comment: I am using Sass 3.4.17 in debian and only three-four line scss file, but it take too mach time to compile. this is fresh installation of all product.plz give solution

Comment: The recommended solution recently is to move to [LibSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass) — which is officially sanctioned, and quickly becoming the primary Sass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, pulling my hair out to find a solution but and finally found one; It is to downgrade.

From 2mins+ of compiling to 25s.

Here's How:

1. You need to install these (if your using OSX):

   http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#installing-using-update-packages
2. Install Bundle

   `gem install bundle`
3. Make a Gemfile in your root folder, name it "`Gemfile`"

```js
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem 'sass', "3.2.9"
gem 'sass-globbing', ">= 1.1.0"
gem 'compass', "0.12.2"
gem 'breakpoint',  "2.0.5"
gem 'singularitygs', "< 2.0.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

4. Install GemFile and update it

   `bundle install && bundle update`
5. Then to run compass with bundle

   `time bundle exec compass compile <path>`

I'm keeping my versions like these for a while, until they fix the performance issues. Hope it helps!